# No credentials have been provided on the appliance for this server

Tags: azure, server, migration, server-migration, azure-migrate

I need your assistance. I am trying to migrate client's servers from on-premises to Azure. These servers are currently running on Hyper-V. I've set up the Azure migrate appliance on the host server to evaluate the servers and send the findings to Azure. The assessment process went smoothly, and I successfully uploaded the results to Azure.

When I viewed the result of the assessment, I keep getting this error

"Error ID

20000

Error message

Credentials not available.

Possible causes

No credentials have been provided on the appliance for this server.

Recommended action

Please go to the appliance configuration manager and provide credentials for the respective server"
[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PSbk.png)

Despite my efforts to troubleshoot, I've been unable to identify the root cause of the problem. I would greatly appreciate your guidance on the recommended course of action to proceed in this situation

I have tried creating a new user for the appliance configuration but I am still getting the same error